# Python - how to move data from class (not instances) to database and link together?

Tags: python, class

I have many classes with class methods. All classes contain some additional "metadata" that I want to move to the DB. I have no idea how to link classes with db entities. It's not a classical Object Relational Mapping, it's Class-With-Code Relational Mapping.

1. Should I use class name + module name (it should be unique globally, but may change during refactor)?
2. Or better solution is to add some unique field to class?
3. Maybe the best solution is to create unique enum and put all classes into a dict (enum as key, class as value)?

Example code:

```py
class SampleClass(CalculatorMainClass):
    data_1 = 1000
    data_2 = {
    2010: {
            1: 847,
        },
    }

    @classmethod
    def calculate(cls, input_data):
        pass
```

Comment: It sounds like you are describing the Django framework, which is designed to abstract DB tables to class models.

Comment: I know django, peewee and sqlalchemy, but I have over 1k classes and all of them have same data fields, so I think, that ORM is not applicable here.

edit: it's a sanic project. I don't want to use Django in this project ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea how to link classes with db entities.

I don't think the is a "best practice" for this so how you do it is really up to you. Approach #2 seems legit, #3 seems complicated but maybe you have a need for that. #1 seems brittle if you anticipate changing the names of your classes. I would recommend putting in a unique identifier as a class variable. Perhaps something like:

```
class SampleClass(CalculatorMainClass):
    _pkey = 1

    @classmethod
    def calculate(cls, input_data):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def metadata(cls):
        # fetch data from database using _pkey
```

Comment: It's hard to keep those _pkeys unique. In #3 is easier to manage pkeys (thanks to enum.unique annotation). Also I need filtering to run only calculations user needs.

Comment: OK, #3 sounds like your answer then. I'm not sure what you mean about the filtering thing. Maybe add more details to your question and someone else can help you out

Comment: I have web service where users can calculate some scores, but I have about 1k calculators, so I don't want to calculate all (because it's unnecessary for user). Then I want to return calculation result and data (from DB).

Comment: is the functionality the same across all the calculators? Like does only the data change?